# Display problem in Cube

Tags: 11.04, compiz

I have Cube set up and running after a few tries, but when the Launcher Auto Hides, it leaves behind a vertical column in it's place with lines and hash marks at the top and bottom and just a gray vertical section in the middle.  If I push the left side of the screen, the launcher reappears as usual but it always leaves this blank vertical space on the screen.

This also appears when the cube is rotated.

**Screenshots:**
[image]

[image]

I have tried a bunch of different settings to no avail.
What am I missing?
Appreciate your help.
Bill

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Using Compiz cube isn't recommended in 11.04 , Also you can post links of your pictures here by a comment. So we can edit your question and help you.

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to link to the photo's so I put them on facebook.  Bill Maiden

Comment: Use http://imgur.com/ to upload your photos, and copy the links.

Comment: Have you tried the instructions for setting up the Cube in [this blog post](http://reformedmusings.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/howto-get-the-compiz-desktop-cube-in-ubuntu-11-04-natty-and-unity/)? (Disclaimer: I have not tried this myself, and as Binarylife pointed out, getting the Cube to work in 11.04 can be difficult and buggy from what I understand.)

Comment: Ok. Here is the link to the desktop  http://i.imgur.com/hHOEf.png     and here is the link to the cube   http://i.imgur.com/K8cqU.png

Comment: Hi Warriorlng64, Thanks for the comeback.  I do have it set up and running and I expect that it is some setting that I have not selected or de-selected.  I have tried just about all that I can think of and no joy so far.

Comment: Hey Binarylife, Can't thank you enough for your help with this.  I have learned more in an hour here than all the reading i've done.  I just hope I can find an answer to why the launcher leaves background behind when it hides.

Comment: Well, I fixed the display.  It no longer has the "rough" edge when the launcher hides and the rough edge is no longer displayed in the cube.  I was looking through the CompizConfig Settings Manager and trying to read what each option does.  There is no explanation given for D-Bus.  I enabled it, the screen flickered as it does with some selections, but nothing changed.  So, I disabled D-Bus and for about 10 seconds the screen flashed and went off and then came back on and the problem was gone.  I did a reboot and sure enough, all is well.  I would just like to understand it now.  Thanks to all

Comment: @Bill If what you did in your last comment solved the issue, can you please post it as an answer below and accept it so others can know you were able to solve the same issue they might be having? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As per a comment:

> Well, I fixed the display.
>
> It no longer has the "rough" edge when the launcher hides and the
>   rough edge is no longer displayed in the cube.
>
> I was looking through the CompizConfig Settings Manager and trying to
>   read what each option does.
>
> There is no explanation given for D-Bus. I enabled it, the screen
>   flickered as it does with some selections, but nothing changed.
>
> So, I disabled D-Bus and for about 10 seconds the screen flashed and
>   went off and then came back on and the problem was gone. I did a
>   r> eboot and sure enough, all is well. I would just like to understand
>   it now.